# Assigning Variables to Tuples in a List

Tags: python, libtcod

I am currently using a function to return a list of tuples (coordinates). I need to assign these coordinates variables so I can use them in a for loop.

My function is:

```
new_connect = astar.get_path(n1x, n1y, n2x, n2y)
```

with `print(new_connect)` I get the output:

```
[(76, 51), (75, 51), (74, 51), (73, 51), (72, 51), (71, 51), (70, 51), (69, 51), ...]
```

I need to assign these tuples variables i.e. (x, y)
So they can be used in the following for loop:

```
for x in range(new_connect):
    for y in range(new_connect):
        self.tiles[x][y].blocked = False
        self.tiles[x][y].block_sight = False
```

Which (should) plot the coordinates and change their tile values.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck working on this and feel like I'm missing something super simple.

Comment: You could always just index into the tuple, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking

```
new_connect = [(76, 51), (75, 51), (74, 51), (73, 51), (72, 51), (71, 51), (70, 51), (69, 51)]
for x, y in new_connect:
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: This worked! I changed my for loop to `for x, y in new_connect:` and kept the rest. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

So, it isn't clear how `range(new_connect)` is actually working. It shouldn't. You should receive a `TypeError`, because a list object is not the correct argument to `range`.

That said, you should be able to create a for loop for a list of tuples by performing the tuple unpacking in the `for` statement itself.

```py
for x, y in astar.get_path(...):
    ...
```

Comment: `range(new_connect)` doesn't work. I just left it there as a placeholder. I'll add that, will remove some lines of code.